# Last value condition foreach in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like that:

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [sendby] => 3
        [refresh] => 0
        [last] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [sendby] => 3
        [refresh] => 1
        [last] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    ( 
        [sendby] => 8
        [refresh] => 1
        [last] => 1
    )
```

I want the value `last` to be 1 when the value `sendby` (here `3` and `8`) is the last of the entire array! How can I do that?

Comment: please be more specific. is very difficult to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: can explain more ?

Comment: i want to put value last  to 1 when the same sendby value is the LAST of the entire foreach

Answer (score 2):

Get the last 2 value and compare with array [3,8]

```
// get array of sendby values
$temp =  array_column($array, 'sendby');
// get array with two last values
$temp =  array_slice($temp, -2);
// Check
if ($temp == [3,8])  {
   $value = 1;
}
else {
   $value = 0;
}
```

or in one line

```
$value = array_slice(array_column($array, 'sendby'), -2) == [3,8] ? 1 : 0;
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/930969)

Update on base of comments

```
// get array with two last values
$temp = array_slice(array_column($array, 'sendby'), -2);

foreach($array as &$x) {
  // If current send by is in $temp array
  if(in_array($x['sendby'], $temp)) {
    $x['last'] = 1;
  }
  else {
    $x['last'] = 0;
  }
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you not to promote oneliners, specially to beginners. It violates SRP and can create bugs which are very difficult to find, including with xdebug.

Comment: upvote because He Understands the Questioners Logic perfectly

Comment: this array was an exemple but it can contain more value ! i just want to put a value last to 1 for each sendby value where its the last of the array !

Comment: @Lokiyou so, if the last two subarrays contains sendby 3 and 8, you want to set last = 1 for each subarrays with sendby 3 and 8?  And what's about other las values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to assist the existing ocurrences of that id. I have an working example (Tested on php sandbox):

```
$array =  array(
    0 => array
    (

        'sendby' => 3,
        'refresh' => 0,
    ),

    1 => array
    (

        'sendby' => 3,
        'refresh' => 1,
    ),

    2 => array
    (

        'sendby' => 8,
        'refresh' => 1,
    )
);  

$ocurrences = [];

foreach($array as $key => $elem ){
    $id = $elem['sendby'];

    if (isset($ocurrences[$id])) {
        $array[$ocurrences[$id]]['last'] = 0;
        $array[$key]['last'] = 1;
        $ocurrences[$id] =  $key;
    } else {
       $ocurrences[$id] = $key;
       $array[$key]['last'] = 1;
    }
}

echo print_r($array, 1);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sendby] => 3
            [refresh] => 0
            [last] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sendby] => 3
            [refresh] => 1
            [last] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sendby] => 8
            [refresh] => 1
            [last] => 1
        )

)
```

Basically I used an array with the ocurrences of the 'sendby' index of the array. The `$occurences` array has the elements with the key of the last checked element.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your array is $array;
You could iterate through it and if it's the last element, then set [last] to 1, else set to 0;

Try to run the below code after your array is populated.

```
$i =1;
foreach($array as $ar) {
    $ar->last = ($i == count($array) && ($ar->sendby == 3 || $ar->sendby == 8)) ?  1 : 0;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: yes but i want the last element with a condition ! here i want the last element for 8 and 3 not only the last element of the array

Comment: @Lokiyou Updated my code so to check if it's last element and only 3 or 8. Would that solve your condition ?

Answer (score 0):

> $count = count($arr) ;

$i = 0;

foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {

if(++$I === $count) {

```
 echo "last element" ;
```

}

}